# How to call web services using json proxy in sencha touch?

Tags: json, web-services, proxy, sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch and web services as well. I have a json file using which i am populating my screen like this:

```
proxy:{
       type:'ajax',
       url:'data/messages.json',

        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'alerts'
        }
    }
```

This works fine for me. But when i try to do the same web services i get this on console:

> OPTIONS
>   http://{server}/aosmobile/alerts?_dc=1336122076647&page=1&start=0&limit=25
>   404 (Not Found)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://{server}/aosmobile/alerts?_dc=1336122076647&page=1&start=0&limit=25.
>   Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I use this method to achieve the same:

```
proxy:{

        type:'rest',
        url:'http://{server}/aosmobile/alerts',
        headers: {                
            'Accept' : 'application/json'                 
        },
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'alerts'
        }
    }
```

The url is deployed. Please do help.

Comment: Same common `Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` error .. Check out other SO posts for its resolution..

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're doing a cross-domain request. Following proxy definition may help:

```
proxy:{
    type:'scripttag',
    url:'http://{server}/aosmobile/alerts',
    reader:
    {
        type:'jsonp',
        rootProperty:'alerts'
    }
}
```